# java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Please help me, i have some problem in here. this is my BandaraMap.java :

```
public class BandaraMap extends FragmentActivity implements OnInfoWindowClickListener, ActionBar.OnNavigationListener
{
    private GoogleMap           map;
    private JSONHelper          json;
    private ProgressDialog      pDialog;
      private LatLng                myLocation;

    private List<Map_POI>   listPOI_Bandara;
    private final String        URL_API     = "http://laraswedding.com/56410097/data_bandara.php";
    private final String        URL_API_Selected1       = "http://laraswedding.com/56410097/data_bandara.php?key=Bandara_Halim_Perdana_Kusuma";
    private final String        URL_API_Selected2       = "http://laraswedding.com/56410097/data_bandara.php?key=Bandara_Soekarno-Hatta";

    public static final String  KEY_NAMA    = "nama";
    public static final String  KEY_ALAMAT  = "alamat";
    public static final String  KEY_LAT_TUJUAN  = "lat_tujuan";
    public static final String  KEY_LNG_TUJUAN  = "lng_tujuan";
    public static final String  KEY_LAT_ASAL    = "lat_asal";
    public static final String  KEY_LNG_ASAL    = "lng_asal";
    //private LatLng user_location;
    // Members for layout
            private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
            private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
            private ListView mDrawerList;
            private CharSequence mTitle;
            private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
            private String[] mTitles;
            ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        /*requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);*/
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_map);
        InitSpinnerLayout();
        InitNavigationDrawableLayout();
        json = new JSONHelper();
        /*myLocation = new LatLng(map.getMyLocation().getLatitude(), map.getMyLocation().getLongitude());
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                new LatLng(myLocation.latitude, myLocation.longitude), 13));*/
        new AsynTaskMain().execute();
        setupMapIfNeeded();
        //bounds = boundsBuilder.build();
        //map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 50));
    }

    private void InitSpinnerLayout() {
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.action_list1,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        //mSpinnerList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        //mSpinnerList.setAdapter(mSpinnerAdapter);
        //mSpinnerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SpinnerItemClickListener());
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
        /*SpinnerAdapter spinneradapter = new SpinnerAdapter(this,
                R.layout.spinner_drawer_item, mSpinners);*/
        actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(mSpinnerAdapter , (OnNavigationListener) this);
        //mSpinners = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.action_list);
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the activities layout.
     */
    private void InitNavigationDrawableLayout() {
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_items_array_bandara);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        NavigationDrawerAdapter adapter = new NavigationDrawerAdapter(this,
                R.layout.drawer_item, mTitles);

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                actionBar.setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                //getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
    ListView.OnItemClickListener {
`@Override`<br/>
`public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,`<br/>
        `long id) {`<br/>
        `switch (position) `<br/>
        `{`<br/>
        `case 0:`<br/>
            `new AsynTaskMain().execute();`<br/>
            `setupMapIfNeeded();`<br/>

            break;
        case 1:
            new AsynTaskMain().isCancelled();
            new AsynTaskMain1().execute();
            setupMapIfNeeded();
            /*for (int i = 0; i < listPOI_Bandara.size(); i++)
            {
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    new LatLng(listPOI_Bandara.get(i).getLat(),
                            listPOI_Bandara.get(i).getLng()), 12));
            }

            /*for (int i = 0; i < listPOI_Bandara.size(); i++)
            {
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(listPOI_Bandara.get(i).getLat(),
                        listPOI_Bandara.get(i).getLng()))
                .title(listPOI_Bandara.get(i).getNama())
                .snippet(listPOI_Bandara.get(i).getAlamat())
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory`
                        .fromResource(R.drawable.marker_bandara_map)));
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    new LatLng(listPOI_Bandara.get(i).getLat(),
                            listPOI_Bandara.get(i).getLng()), 12));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bandara Halim Perdana Kusuma", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }*/
            break;
        case 2:
            new AsynTaskMain().isCancelled();
            new AsynTaskMain2().execute();
            setupMapIfNeeded();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
`}`<br/><br/>

`}`<br/><br/>

    private void setupMapIfNeeded()
    {
        if (map == null)
        {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.maps);
            map = supportMapFragment.getMap();
            map.setTrafficEnabled(true);

            if (map != null)
            {
                setupMap();
            }
        }

    }

    private void setupMap()
    {
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
        moveToMyLocation();
    }

    private void moveToMyLocation()
    {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));
        //user_location = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        if (location != null)
        {
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 13));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (R.string.Toast), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            /*marker_user = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))
                        .title("Posisi Anda Saat Ini")
                        //.snippet("       Tangerang-Banten  ")
                        //.flat(true)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                .fromResource(R.drawable.marker_bandara_map)));
            marker_user.showInfoWindow();*/
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_about:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class));
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long itemId) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:

            break;
        case 1:
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),BandaraAR.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            //mArchitectView.load("video.html");
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
      }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        int resCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
        if (resCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
        {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resCode, this, 1);
        }
    }

     @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            //Handle the back ImageButton
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {          
                checkBack();             
                return true;
            }       
            else {
                return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
            }

        }

        private void checkBack()
        {
            Intent kembali = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MasukAplikasi.class);
            startActivity(kembali);
        }

    private class AsynTaskMain extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            pDialog.dismiss();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {

                @Override
                public void run()
                {   
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    for (int i = 0; i < listPOI_Bandara.size(); i++)
                    {
                        if (i != listPOI_Bandara.size() - 1)
                        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(new LatLng(listPOI_Bandara.get(i).getLat(),
                                        listPOI_Bandara.get(i).getLng()))
                                .title(listPOI_Bandara.get(i).getNama())
                                .snippet(listPOI_Bandara.get(i).getAlamat())
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                        .fromResource(R.drawable.marker_bandara_map)));
                        else if (i == listPOI_Bandara.size() - 1)
                        {
                            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                                    new LatLng(-6.175392,106.827153), 10));
                                /*map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                                        new LatLng(listPOI_Bandara.get(i).getLat(),
                                                listPOI_Bandara.get(i).getLng()), 10));*/

                                //boundsBuilder.include(new LatLng(listPOI_Bandara.get(i).getLat(), listPOI_Bandara.get(i).getLng()));
                                //marker_bandara.showInfoWindow();

                        }

                    }
                }
            });

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(BandaraMap.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading....");
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            JSONObject jObject = json.getJSONFromURL(URL_API);
            listPOI_Bandara = json.getPOI_BandaraAll(jObject);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private class AsynTaskMain1 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            pDialog.dismiss();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {

                @Override
                public void run()
                {   
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    for (int i = 0; i < listPOI_Bandara.size(); i++)
                    {
                        /*if (i != listPOI_Bandara.size() - 1)
                        {*/
                            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(listPOI_Bandara.get(i).getLat(),
                                    listPOI_Bandara.get(i).getLng()))
                            .title(listPOI_Bandara.get(i).getNama())
                            .snippet(listPOI_Bandara.get(i).getAlamat())
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                    .fromResource(R.drawable.marker_bandara_map)));
                            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                                new LatLng(listPOI_Bandara.get(i).getLat(),
                                    listPOI_Bandara.get(i).getLng()), 12));
                        //}
                        /*else if (i == listPOI_Bandara.size() -1)
                        {

                        }*/

                        //boundsBuilder.include(new LatLng(listPOI_Bandara.get(i).getLat(), listPOI_Bandara.get(i).getLng()));
                        //marker_bandara.showInfoWindow();

                    }
                }
            });

            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bandara Halim Perdana Kusuma", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(BandaraMap.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading....");
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            JSONObject jObject1 = json.getJSONFromURL(URL_API_Selected1);
            listPOI_Bandara = json.getPOI_BandaraAll(jObject1);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private class AsynTaskMain2 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            pDialog.dismiss();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {

                @Override
                public void run()
                {   
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    for (int i = 0; i < listPOI_Bandara.size(); i++)
                    {
                        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(listPOI_Bandara.get(i).getLat(),
                                listPOI_Bandara.get(i).getLng()))
                        .title(listPOI_Bandara.get(i).getNama())
                        .snippet(listPOI_Bandara.get(i).getAlamat())
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                .fromResource(R.drawable.marker_bandara_map)));
                        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                                new LatLng(listPOI_Bandara.get(i).getLat(),
                                        listPOI_Bandara.get(i).getLng()), 12));

                        //boundsBuilder.include(new LatLng(listPOI_Bandara.get(i).getLat(), listPOI_Bandara.get(i).getLng()));
                        //marker_bandara.showInfoWindow();

                    }
                }
            });

            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bandara Soekarno-Hatta", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(BandaraMap.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading....");
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            JSONObject jObject2 = json.getJSONFromURL(URL_API_Selected2);
            listPOI_Bandara = json.getPOI_BandaraAll(jObject2);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker_tujuan)
    {
        // marker id -> m0, m1, m2 dst..
        String id = marker_tujuan.getId();
        id = id.substring(1);

        myLocation = new LatLng(map.getMyLocation().getLatitude(), map.getMyLocation().getLongitude());

        if (myLocation != null)
        {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString(KEY_NAMA, listPOI_Bandara.get(Integer.parseInt(id)).getNama());
            bundle.putString(KEY_ALAMAT, listPOI_Bandara.get(Integer.parseInt(id)).getAlamat());
            bundle.putDouble(KEY_LAT_TUJUAN, marker_tujuan.getPosition().latitude);
            bundle.putDouble(KEY_LNG_TUJUAN, marker_tujuan.getPosition().longitude);
            bundle.putDouble(KEY_LAT_ASAL, myLocation.latitude);
            bundle.putDouble(KEY_LNG_ASAL, myLocation.longitude);

            Intent i = new Intent(BandaraMap.this, InfoTempatActivity.class);
            i.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(i);

        } else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Tidak dapat menemukan lokasi anda ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

And, this is my JSONHelper.java :

```
public class JSONHelper
{
    private InputStream     is              = null;
    private JSONObject      jsonObject      = null;
    private String          json            = "";

    private final String    TAG_BANDARA     = "data_bandara";
    private final String    TAG_PELABUHAN   = "data_pelabuhan";
    private final String    TAG_STASIUN     = "data_stasiun";
    private final String    TAG_TERMINAL    = "data_terminal";
    private final String    TAG_ID          = "id";
    private final String    TAG_NAMA        = "nama";
    private final String    TAG_ALAMAT      = "alamat";
    private final String    TAG_LAT         = "lat";
    private final String    TAG_LNG         = "lng";
    private final String    TAG_ROUTES      = "routes";
    private final String    TAG_LEGS        = "legs";
    private final String    TAG_STEPS       = "steps";
    private final String    TAG_POLYLINE    = "polyline";
    private final String    TAG_POINTS      = "points";
    private final String    TAG_START       = "start_location";
    private final String    TAG_END         = "end_location";

    public JSONObject getJSONFromURL(String url)
    {
        try
        {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        try
        {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);

        } catch (JSONException e)
        {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        return jsonObject;
    }

    public ArrayList<Map_POI> getPOI_BandaraAll(JSONObject jobj)
    {
        ArrayList<Map_POI> listPOI_Bandara = new ArrayList<Map_POI>();

        try
        {
            JSONArray arrayPOI_Bandara = jobj.getJSONArray(TAG_BANDARA);

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayPOI_Bandara.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject jobject = arrayPOI_Bandara.getJSONObject(i);

                Log.d("log", "muter ke " + i);
                listPOI_Bandara.add(new Map_POI( jobject.getInt(TAG_ID), jobject.getString(TAG_NAMA), jobject
                        .getString(TAG_ALAMAT), jobject
                        .getDouble(TAG_LAT), jobject.getDouble(TAG_LNG)));

            }
        } catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return listPOI_Bandara;
    }

    public ArrayList<Map_POI> getPOI_PelabuhanAll(JSONObject jobj)
    {
        ArrayList<Map_POI> listPOI_Pelabuhan = new ArrayList<Map_POI>();

        try
        {
            JSONArray arrayPOI_Pelabuhan = jobj.getJSONArray(TAG_PELABUHAN);

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayPOI_Pelabuhan.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject jobject = arrayPOI_Pelabuhan.getJSONObject(i);

                Log.d("log", "muter ke " + i);
                listPOI_Pelabuhan.add(new Map_POI( jobject.getInt(TAG_ID), jobject.getString(TAG_NAMA), jobject
                        .getString(TAG_ALAMAT), jobject
                        .getDouble(TAG_LAT), jobject.getDouble(TAG_LNG)));

            }
        } catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return listPOI_Pelabuhan;
    }

    public ArrayList<Map_POI> getPOI_StasiunAll(JSONObject jobj)
    {
        ArrayList<Map_POI> listPOI_Stasiun = new ArrayList<Map_POI>();

        try
        {
            JSONArray arrayPOI_Stasiun = jobj.getJSONArray(TAG_STASIUN);

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayPOI_Stasiun.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject jobject = arrayPOI_Stasiun.getJSONObject(i);

                Log.d("log", "muter ke " + i);
                listPOI_Stasiun.add(new Map_POI( jobject.getInt(TAG_ID), jobject.getString(TAG_NAMA), jobject
                        .getString(TAG_ALAMAT), jobject
                        .getDouble(TAG_LAT), jobject.getDouble(TAG_LNG)));

            }
        } catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return listPOI_Stasiun;
    }

    public ArrayList<Map_POI> getPOI_TerminalAll(JSONObject jobj)
    {
        ArrayList<Map_POI> listPOI_Terminal = new ArrayList<Map_POI>();

        try
        {
            JSONArray arrayPOI_Terminal = jobj.getJSONArray(TAG_TERMINAL);

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayPOI_Terminal.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject jobject = arrayPOI_Terminal.getJSONObject(i);

                Log.d("log", "muter ke " + i);
                listPOI_Terminal.add(new Map_POI( jobject.getInt(TAG_ID), jobject.getString(TAG_NAMA), jobject
                        .getString(TAG_ALAMAT), jobject
                        .getDouble(TAG_LAT), jobject.getDouble(TAG_LNG)));

            }
        } catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return listPOI_Terminal;
    }

    /*
     * Untuk decode Polyline
     * 
     * @params String
     * 
     * @return List<LatLng>
     */
    private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded)
    {
        List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;
        while (index < len)
        {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do
            {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;
            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do
            {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng position = new LatLng((double) lat / 1E5, (double) lng / 1E5);
            poly.add(position);
        }
        return poly;

    }

    /*
     * Untuk mendapatkan direction
     * 
     * @params JSONObject
     * 
     * @return List<LatLng>
     */
    public List<LatLng> getDirection(JSONObject jObj)
    {

        List<LatLng> directions = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

        try
        {
            JSONObject objRoute = jObj.getJSONArray(TAG_ROUTES).getJSONObject(0);
            JSONObject objLegs = objRoute.getJSONArray(TAG_LEGS).getJSONObject(0);
            JSONArray arraySteps = objLegs.getJSONArray(TAG_STEPS);
            for (int wi2t = 0; wi2t < arraySteps.length(); wi2t++)
            {
                JSONObject step = arraySteps.getJSONObject(wi2t);
                JSONObject objStart = step.getJSONObject(TAG_START);
                JSONObject objEnd = step.getJSONObject(TAG_END);
                double latStart = objStart.getDouble(TAG_LAT);
                double lngStart = objStart.getDouble(TAG_LNG);

                directions.add(new LatLng(latStart, lngStart));

                JSONObject poly = step.getJSONObject(TAG_POLYLINE);
                String encodedPoly = poly.getString(TAG_POINTS);

                List<LatLng> decodedPoly = decodePoly(encodedPoly);
                for (int eka = 0; eka < decodedPoly.size(); eka++)
                {
                    directions.add(new LatLng(decodedPoly.get(eka).latitude, decodedPoly.get(eka).longitude));
                }

                double latEnd = objEnd.getDouble(TAG_LAT);
                double lngEnd = objEnd.getDouble(TAG_LNG);
                directions.add(new LatLng(latEnd, lngEnd));

            }
        } catch (JSONException e)
        {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        return directions;
    }
}
```

and here's my problem on logcat :

```
`09-17 02:43:37.969: W/dalvikvm(14200): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41dc4930)`<br/>
`09-17 02:43:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14200): FATAL EXCEPTION: main`<br/>
`09-17 02:43:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14200): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1`<br/>
`09-17 02:43:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14200):   at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)`<br/>
`09-17 02:43:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14200):   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)`<br/>
`09-17 02:43:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14200):   at com.slowbrocorp.aplikasiargpsdangistempattransportasiumum.BandaraMap.onInfoWindowClick(BandaraMap.java:571)`<br/>
`09-17 02:43:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14200):   at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$12.e(Unknown Source)`<br/>
`09-17 02:43:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14200):   at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.g$a.onTransact(Unknown Source)`<br/>
`09-17 02:43:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14200):   at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:310)`<br/>
`09-17 02:43:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14200):   at gsh.a(SourceFile:82)`<br/>
`09-17 02:43:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14200):   at oup.b(Unknown Source)`<br/>
`09-17 02:43:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14200):   at oqn.g(Unknown Source)`<br/>
`09-17 02:43:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14200):   at oqn.a(Unknown Source)`<br/>
`09-17 02:43:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14200):   at okj.b(Unknown Source)`<br/>
`09-17 02:43:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14200):   at ole.onSingleTapConfirmed(Unknown Source)`<br/>
`09-17 02:43:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14200):   at nyi.onSingleTapConfirmed(Unknown Source)`<br/>
`09-17 02:43:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14200):   at nyk.handleMessage(Unknown Source)`<br/>
`09-17 02:43:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14200):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)`<br/>
`09-17 02:43:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14200):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)`<br/>
`09-17 02:43:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14200):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5061)`<br/>
`09-17 02:43:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14200):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)`<br/>
`09-17 02:43:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14200):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)`<br/>
`09-17 02:43:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14200):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)`<br/>
`09-17 02:43:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14200):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)`<br/>
`09-17 02:43:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14200):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`<br/>
```

When i selected case 2 on draweritemclicklistener and execute AsynTaskMain2(), it's stop working. please help me to fix this :(

Comment: You should get familiar with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) or [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What you have tried so far to isolate the root cause and fix it?

Comment: Pay more attention to what is registered on your StackTrace. It will help you a lot.

Comment: Not much, i just combine some code , fix the code position, etc. but, it still not working after all :( @user3666197

Answer (score 1):

Your stack trace says the following:

```
09-17 02:43:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14200): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
09-17 02:43:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14200):   at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
09-17 02:43:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14200):   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
09-17 02:43:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14200):   at com.slowbrocorp.aplikasiargpsdangistempattransportasiumum.BandaraMap.onInfoWindowClick(BandaraMap.java:571)
```

This means: a call to ArrayList.get() was made from MandaraMap.onInfoWindowClick() line 571, with an argument of 1, which wasn't legal because there is only one element in the ArrayList.

Which line is line 571?  I don't see any call to `get()` in `onInfoWindowClick()` in the code you posted, which makes me think that the code you posted isn't the code you're running.

Comment: hmm, maybe that's the problem was, line 571 : `bundle.putString(KEY_NAMA, listPOI_Bandara.get(Integer.parseInt(id)).getNama());`

Comment: You're right, I missed that call to `ArrayList.get()` when I was reading through the code.  Do you have any guarantee that the second character of the ID string will be 0 for the first item in the list, 1 for the second item in the list, etc.?  And are you sure you'll only have at most 10 items in the list (0-9), since you're only reading a single character?  This seems like you'd be better off using a HashMap with your id String as the key and your `Map_POI` as the value, instead of an ArrayList.

Comment: hmm, yes, pretty sure. i guaranteed that. Could you help me to add HashMap function to my code, i'm still beginner in android programming. please. hehehe. thanks a lot for your help :) @Tim

Comment: Instead of declaring `private List<Map_POI>   listPOI_Bandara;`, declare `private Map<String, Map_POI> listPOI_Bandara = new HashMap<>();`  Then whenever you would have done `listPOI_Bandara.add(myMapPOI)`, instead do `listPOI_Bandara.put(id, myMapPOI);`, and whenever you would have done `listPOI_Bandara.get(Integer.parseInt(id.substring(1))`, instead do `listPOI_Bandara.get(id)`. And if you need to iterate through all the keys or values in the map, you can do a `for` loop on `listPOI_Bandara.keySet()`,  `listPOI_Bandara.valueSet()`,  or `listPOI_Bandara.entrySet()` depending on what you want.